# How can I get only the headings and their subheadings from word file

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, office-interop

I want to get all the headings along their sub-headings separately from a word file programmatically Using c# for example i have following content :

> - HEADING 1 XYZ
>
> heading 2 heading 3
>
> - HEADING 1 ABC
> - HEADING 1 DEF
>
> heading 2 lorem ispum

so my code should return me:

> - Heading 1 XYZ
>
>   heading 2  heading 3

seperately and similarly remaining headings and subheadings also.

I have tried this but my code returns me all the headings and subheadings together not seperately , here's my code for getting the headings:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph paragraph in oMyDoc.Paragraphs )
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style style = 
        paragraph.get_Style() as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style;

    string styleName = style.NameLocal;
    string text = paragraph.Range.Text;

    if (styleName == "Title")
    {
        title = text.ToString();
    }
    else if (styleName == "Subtitle")
    {
        st = text.ToString() + "\n";
    }
    else if (styleName=="Heading 1")
    {
        heading1[h1c] = text.ToString()+"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to get answers, it's best to show the code that you've tried so far and explain what's not working.  People generally don't want to do your work for you.

Comment: I have added the code now.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that you have title and st declared as strings, every iteration through the loop the old values are being replaced with the current values. If you use a list, you can add the text and subtitle to them. You can then easily do what you want with them.

```
List<String> title = new List<String>();
List<String> st = new List<String>();

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph paragraph in oMyDoc.Paragraphs )
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style style = paragraph.get_Style() as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style;
            string styleName = style.NameLocal;
            string text = paragraph.Range.Text;


            if (styleName == "Title")
            {
                title.Add(text.ToString());
            }
            else if (styleName == "Subtitle")
            {
                st.Add(text.ToString());

            }
            else if (styleName=="Heading 1")
            {
                heading1[h1c] = text.ToString()+"\n";


            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Heading" is not really reliable if you want to get the whole outline (like what's in the Table of Content), because all the styles can be renamed / copied. So some other styles like "H1" or "标题1"(Chinese word for "Heading1") can act as heading and appear in Table of Content and Navigation Panel.

I even saw "Normal" acting as headings in a doc. That made me give up using styles to find headings.

Try paragraph.OutlineLevel instead. Its value ranges from WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel1 to 9 (means it's some kind of "heading"), and ends with WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevelBodyText (means it's just text body).

Here is my code. I even built a tree-like heading list (one heading each line).

```
public static class WordBridge
{
    public static Dictionary<WdOutlineLevel, string> Level2Spaces = new Dictionary<WdOutlineLevel, string>()
    {
        {WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel1, ""},
        {WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel2, " "},
        {WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel3, "  "},
        {WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel4, "   "},
        {WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel5, "    "},
        {WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel6, "     "},
        {WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel7, "      "},
        {WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel8, "       "},
        {WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevel9, "        "},
        {WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevelBodyText, "         "},
    };
    public static string GetOutlines(object? sender, Document currentWordDoc)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var countFinished = 0;
        foreach (Paragraph paragraph in currentWordDoc.Paragraphs)
        {
            countFinished++;
            (sender as BackgroundWorker)?.ReportProgress(countFinished);
            if (paragraph.OutlineLevel == WdOutlineLevel.wdOutlineLevelBodyText)
                continue;
            if (Level2Spaces.ContainsKey(paragraph.OutlineLevel))
                sb.Append(Level2Spaces[paragraph.OutlineLevel] + paragraph.Range.Text);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

I might make it a real tree at near future.
Btw, remove the ReportProgress things if you do not have a progress bar. But it's really slow because of single thread.

Answer (score -2):

```
//This will return you headers and text below of corrousponding header

    private List<Tuple<string, string>> GetPlainTextByHeaderFromWordDoc(string docname)
    {
        #region for Plain text collection from document
        List<Tuple<string, string>> docPlainTextWithHeaderList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

        string headerText = string.Empty;
        string finalTextBelowHeader = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            Document doc = ReadMsWord(docname, objCommonVariables);

            if (doc.Paragraphs.Count > 0)
            {
                //heading with 1st paragraph
                foreach (Paragraph paragraph in doc.Paragraphs)
                {
                    Style style = paragraph.get_Style() as Style;
                    headerText = string.Empty;
                    finalTextBelowHeader = string.Empty;

                    if (style.NameLocal == "Heading 1")
                    {
                    headerText = paragraph.Range.Text.TrimStart().TrimEnd();

                        //reading 1st paragraph of each section
                        for (int i = 0; i < doc.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (paragraph.Next(i) != null)
                            {
                                Style yle = paragraph.Next(i).get_Style() as Style;
                                if (yle.NameLocal != "Heading 1")
                                {
                                    finalTextBelowHeader += paragraph.Next(i).Range.Text.ToString();
                                }
                                else if (yle.NameLocal == "Heading 1" && !headerText.Contains(paragraph.Next(i).Range.Text.ToString()))
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        string header = Regex.Replace(headerText, "[^a-zA-Z\\s]", string.Empty).TrimStart().TrimEnd();
                        string belowText = Regex.Replace(finalTextBelowHeader, @"\s+", String.Empty);
                        belowText = belowText.Trim().Replace("\a", string.Empty);

                        docPlainTextWithHeaderList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(header, belowText));

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
             //error msg: unable to read
            }

            doc.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
        }
 }

  //This will read and return word document
  private Document ReadMsWord(string docName)
     {
    Document docs = new Document();
    try
    {
        // variable to store file path
        string FilePath = @"C:\Kaustubh_Tupe\WordRepository/docName.docx";
        // create word application
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        // create object of missing value
        object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        // create object of selected file path
        object path = FilePath;
        // set file path mode
        object readOnly = false;
        // open Destination                
        docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly,
            ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
            ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

        //select whole data from active window Destination
        docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
        // handover the data to cllipboard
        docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
        // clipboard create reference of idataobject interface which transfer the data
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    return docs;
}
```